# Dyanmically change a classes namespace in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

Is it possible to change a classes namespace in PHP dynamically?

This is purely for dev/test environments, I want to see if I can override `mysql_query`
and currently installing PECL apd isnt an option.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible! For your requirements better solution is to register autoload function in your index.php file. After get singleton instance where you can get environment status. 
For example `$environent = Env::getInstance()->environment()` Your autoload get environment value ad in dependency to that value do autoload.

For example all your production class are located on `production/class/here/goes/namespace/MyClass1.php`

And all your debug class are located on `debug/class/here/goes/namespace/MyClass1.php`

```
    function __autoload($class)
    {
        $parts = explode('\\', $class); // namespace
        $dir = Env::getInstance()->environment(); //string "production" or "debug"
        require(
            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$dir .
            implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $parts).
            '.php'

        );

    }
```

Something like that